# Flutter Viedeo Player like Youtube, Amazon Prime

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-video-player, flutter-localizations

How to download video from online(api response) and store it in local device and play that video using video player in flutter app.
Eg : Amazon Prime, Youtube, Netflix...

Comment: you can play video from api with this package https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter

Comment: to save data locally refer this https://pusher.com/tutorials/local-data-flutter/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

On an outline to give you an idea, you would need to consider

1. Download video, use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to download your video files to your local path.

ex.

```
 try {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await dio.download(url, "${dir.path}/myFile.mp4", onProgress: (rec, total) {
      print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");
    });
  } catch (e) {
```

We could use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get the applicationDocumentDirectory to save the files to local dir.

2. DB to save the files path of locally saved files, you could use [objectdb](https://pub.dev/packages/objectdb), [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)
3. Use the video_player plugin to play the asset file saved locally.